# how to get parallel build job result in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins job run multiple builds in parallel as below:

```
def branches = [:]


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  def index = i 
  branches["branch${i}"] = {
    build job: 'Test', parameters: [
      string(name: 'param1', value:'test_param'),
      string(name:'dummy', value: "${index}")]
  }
}
parallel branches
```

For the above code I want to print all build result. So how can I get build result (e.g. `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE`...) of all parallel jobs?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print all branches result in the same console
you can do it like this

```
def branches = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 def index = i 
  branches["branch${i}"] = {
  build job: 'Test', parameters: [
  string(name: 'param1', value:'test_param'),
  string(name:'dummy', value: "${index}")]
 }
  println currentBuild.result
}
parallel branches
```

`currentBuild.result` holds status of the build so if you print it in each branch you will get what you need. If the stage